# Почему Symfony3 forwarding уходит в цикл?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Route("/s/{query}", name="search")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, $query = null, $sid = null, $key = null)
{
    if ($sid && $key) {
        $captcha = [
            'captcha_sid' => $sid,
            'captcha_key' => $key
        ];
    }
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('search', TextType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $VKAPI = $this->get('vk_music');
    dump($request);
    if (isset($query)) {
        //$form->get('search')->setData($query);
        if ($sid && $key) {
            $tracks = $VKAPI->search($query, $captcha);
        } else {
            $tracks = $VKAPI->search($query);
        }
    } else {
        if ($sid && $key) {
            $tracks = $VKAPI->getPopular($captcha);
        } else {
            $tracks = $VKAPI->getPopular();
        }
    }

    dump($tracks);

    if (isset($tracks['error'])) {
        $errorInfo = $tracks['error'];

        $params = [
            'sid' => $errorInfo['captcha']['sid'],
            'img' => $errorInfo['captcha']['img']
        ];
        if (isset($query)) {
            $params['query'] = $query;
        }

        return $this->forward('MusicBundle:Default:captcha', $params);
    } else {
        return $this->render('MusicBundle:Default:index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'tracks' => $tracks
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * @Route("/captcha")
 */
public function captchaAction(Request $request, $sid, $img, $query = null)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('key', TextType::class)
        ->add('sid', HiddenType::class, ['data' => $sid])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $params = [
            'sid' => $data['sid'],
            'key' => $data['key']
        ];

        if (isset($query)) {
            $params['query'] = $query;
        }

        return $this->forward('MusicBundle:Default:index', $params);
    } else {
        return $this->render('MusicBundle:Default:captcha.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'captcha_img' => $img
        ]);
    }
}
```

Открываю site/app_dev.php/s/text, выводит капчу. Пишу ее, сабмичу, и страница бесконечно загружается. Я так понимаю что все уходит в цикл. А на самом деле я ничего не понимаю. Если кому-то предоставить нужно куски сервиса - напишите. Но тут вроде все понятно как работает.

Comment: А как вы поняли что она уходит в цикл? Логах PHP есть ошибки ?

Comment: Чисто предполагаю что уходит в цикл.
1) Если от index форвардить на captcha, где есть форма. И если ее засабмитить, и обратно зафорвардить на Index, и если в index тоже есть форма, и если ее изменять (допустим data подставлять) то симфони ругнется мол форма засабмичена а ты меняешь data. Я предполагаю что что-то не так при форвардинге с активными формами.
2) В логах ошибок нет